# Chrome cast : is multichannel HE-AAC sent in HDMI bitstream pass-though mode to AV receiver?

Tags: chromecast

is multichannel HE-AAC sent in HDMI bitstream pass-though mode to AV receiver?
 or
 Chromecast resident SW decodes multi channel and then down mixes it to 2 channel before sending to AVR?

or chromecast decodes 5.1 multi channel HE-AAC to 5.1 LPCM before sending over to HDMI?

My Denon 4308CI shows

1) for stream Big Buck Bunny (http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/big_buck_bunny_1080p.mp4) : as FL (front left) and FR (front right) text high lighted

2) for HE-AAC channel check : (http://streaming.dolby.com/ftproot/fraunhofer/ChID-BLITS-EBU.mp4): All 5.1 channels And ** MULTI Channel Direct" as text. So not sure.

Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Chromecast is capable of decoding AAC 5.1 content when said Chromecast device is plugged in to a 5.1 audio capable HDMI sink. Player must check for codec "aac51" using canPlayType and should request an AAC 5.1 stream, only when Chromecast indicates AAC 5.1 support as response to canPlayType.

Comment: To make sure I understand. When HDMI sink device is capable of handling 5.1, chromecast device decodes 51. AAC/HE-AAC and outputs 5.1 LPCM. Right?

Comment: @AliNaddaf do you have a link to canPlayType API docs? I couldn't find them.

Comment: You mean as in general reference to it? Like: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#dom-navigator-canplaytype ?

Comment: Gotcha, I thought you were saying the method was available in the chromecast api.

Comment: Chromecast runs chrome and has that API as well.

Comment: with the chromecast plugged into my 5.1 capable receiver and running `$('video')[0].canPlayType('aac51')` in the receiver debugging console, I get empty string.

Comment: my bad...this gives back a 'maybe': `$('video')[0].canPlayType('video/mp4;codecs="aac51"')` . Do you know in what cases you would get back a 'probably'?

Comment: It is in the specs that I provided a link to.

Comment: I guess I'm just confused because `aac51` doesn't seem like a proper codec to be passing in. I can replace it with `blahblah` and I still get back `maybe`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49081/discussion-between-flynfish-and-ali-naddaf)